# Reqular expression for alpha numeric and empty spaces

Tags: c#

here i am entering alphanumeric characters with empty spaces. but this expression fails

```
// Function to Check for AlphaNumeric.
public bool IsAlphaNumeric(String strToCheck)
{
    Regex objAlphaNumericPattern = new Regex(@"[a-zA-Z0-9\s]*");
    return objAlphaNumericPattern.IsMatch(strToCheck);
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string straddres = "2";
    straddres = TextBox1.Text;
    if (!IsAlphaNumeric(straddres.Trim()))
    {
        Label1.Text = "Error";
    }
    else
    {
        Label1.Text = "Success";
    }
}
```

ex:

```
123 abc, 23 2322 erwer
```

these words should get statsified please let me know  where my expression is  wrong

ex:

```
@#23,#$ 34,@&* 34s
```

should bot  get satisfied

Comment: You are using `*` which means that _any_ string will match (`*` == zero or more).

Comment: You have a comma in your first string.

Answer (score 3):

the  expression solved my issue

```
@"^[A-Za-z0-9 ]+$"
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `*` with `+` in your expression. `*` will match for zero characters, so you'll get a match for everything using that, even the empty string. `+` means that you have to have at least one character matching.

You might consider adding `^` at the start of the string and `$` at the end of the expression to make it match the entire string, if that is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

`\s` is a pre-defined character class. All pre-defined character classes lose their special meanings inside a user-defined character class. Your regular expression will match alphanumeric or a slash (the extra `s` is redundant as `a-z` will match that).

Either change the `\s` to a space (`[a-zA-Z 0-9]`), or if you need to capture any kind of whitespace (not just ASCII 32), try using `([a-zA-Z0-9]|\s)*`.

Warning: The alternate match of `\s` will also capture entire chunks of just whitespace.

Comment: That's generally not true. \s will work just as good within character classes as outside in most regex engines. It's only singular character operators like * and + who loses their meaning inside the class.

Answer (score 0):

You need to compare *match value* against input string.

```
string pattern = @"[a-zA-Z0-9\s]*";
Match match = Regex.Match(str, pattern);
if (match.Value == str)
    Console.WriteLine("Valid");
else
   Console.WriteLine("Invalid");
```